# How to prevent the form binding of a perticular field in golang echo framework?

Tags: forms, go, bind, go-echo

For example
type student struct{
ID  int `form:"-"`
Name string `form:"name"`
Details string `form:"details"`
}

Here i do not want bind function in echo to bind id from the create student request to ID. but if i post like.
-:1
name:student
details:student

it will bind `-` value to ID which i do not want.

And if i skip form tag as shown below
type student struct{
ID  int
Name string `form:"name"`
Details string `form:"details"`
}

then do a post request

id:1
name:student
details:student

now the bind function will bind id with ID.

the problem is I am not able to skip binding for ID field

Comment: please share your code for clarification.

Comment: AFAICT this is not currently possible, not with the default binder. You'll need to use a custom binder, or no binder at all and instead use some 3rd party lib that does form-unmarshaling the way you need it to be done. If you care looking deeper into this you'll find the main binding code [here](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/bind.go#L86-L169).